# Run to the next breakpoint shortcut in IntelliJ for macOS

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using a MacBook Pro and IntelliJ IDEA.

"*Run to cursor*" keyboard shortcut is <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>, but what's the keyboard shortcut for "*Run to next breakpoint*"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put and hold cursor over the Resume button and you will see the shortcut.

[image]